# how to access a dictionary in list which is inside a string?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

```
value = "[
{"Id":2,"Name":"Sony","WarehouseName":"Bangalore"},
{"Id":3,"Name":"JBL","WarehouseName":"Nanjangud"},
{"Id":4,"Name":"Skull Candy 2","WarehouseName":"Mysore"},
{"Id":5,"Name":"Skull Candy 3","WarehouseName":"Mysore"}
]"
```

This is the string which contains a list in which there is a dictionary. How to get the 'Name' :

Sony

JBL

Skull Candy 2

Skull Candy 3

Comment: This is a JSON string. You need to parse it first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `json` module for this

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(value)
[{'Id': 2, 'Name': 'Sony', 'WarehouseName': 'Bangalore'},
 {'Id': 3, 'Name': 'JBL', 'WarehouseName': 'Nanjangud'},
 {'Id': 4, 'Name': 'Skull Candy 2', 'WarehouseName': 'Mysore'},
 {'Id': 5, 'Name': 'Skull Candy 3', 'WarehouseName': 'Mysore'}]
```

To get all the names

```
>>> [d['Name'] for d in json.loads(value)]
['Sony', 'JBL', 'Skull Candy 2', 'Skull Candy 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json` or the `ast` module.

**Ex:**

```
import json
value = """[{"Id":2,"Name":"Sony","WarehouseName":"Bangalore"},{"Id":3,"Name":"JBL","WarehouseName":"Nanjangud"},{"Id":4,"Name":"Skull Candy 2","WarehouseName":"Mysore"},{"Id":5,"Name":"Skull Candy 3","WarehouseName":"Mysore"}]"""
print( json.loads(value) )
```

or

```
import ast
value = """[{"Id":2,"Name":"Sony","WarehouseName":"Bangalore"},{"Id":3,"Name":"JBL","WarehouseName":"Nanjangud"},{"Id":4,"Name":"Skull Candy 2","WarehouseName":"Mysore"},{"Id":5,"Name":"Skull Candy 3","WarehouseName":"Mysore"}]"""
print( ast.literal_eval(value) )

print( map(lambda x: x["Name"], ast.literal_eval(value)) )
```

**Output:**

```
[u'Sony', u'JBL', u'Skull Candy 2', u'Skull Candy 3']
```